# Magento 1.5 CE display search function in navigation bar

Tags: search, magento, navigation

I am using Magento CE v1.5. Modern theme. I would like to display Search bar on the right hand side in the Navigation bar. Basically category menus on the left and search function on the right on a horizontal menu.

I have replaced **top.bar** with **top.menu** in **catalogsearch.xml**. The search function displays on the right with the following CSS

**.form-search** { margin:3px auto; float:right; position:absolute; right:20px; top:70px; }

I am just wondering do I need to do anything to top.phtml file because many other tutorials suggest you need to add

**getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>**

My search displays without the above code in the **top.phtml** file.

Please suggest the correct way to go about achieveing search in the navigation bar in CE v1.5. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If, `getChildHtml()` not loaded in a template that you work on, you can't show the block that you want. Try the following snippet :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.search')->toHtml() ?>
```